# Managing Activities inside ActivityGroup

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost, activitygroup

I am experimenting with `TabHost` and `ActivityGroup` when I noticed that if I pressed back on one activity, the whole `ActivityGroup` is destroyed. As such, I created a list of Views representing my activities. However, this causes my previous activity to lost its state. I even setup the `freezesText` of my `EditText` on the previous activity to 'true' but this does not help in preserving its value.

Can you explain me how the `ActivityGroup` works and how it manages it sub-activities? Right now, I get the impression that `ActivityGroup` only switches the views, not activities. Am I correct with that? I am getting more and more confused here. How can I make it work such that if I pressed back on one activity, the previous activity will be recovered based on its last state? (Like what happens when a normal activity calls another activity then the user presses back.)

This is what I want to happen:

- ActivityGroupA (ActivityGroupA was launched. User inputs details on ActivityGroupA.)
- ActivityGroupA > ActivityB (User presses 'submit'. ActivityGroupA calls ActivityB.)
- ActivityB > ActivityGroupA (User presses 'cancel'. ActivityB is destroyed. ActivityGroupA is now the top of the stack again.)

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void back()
{
    if ( history.size() > 1 )
    {
        history.remove(history.size() - 1);
        View v = history.get(history.size() - 1);
        v.setFocusable(true);
        v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        v.clearFocus();
        setContentView(v);
    }
    else 
        this.finish();
}
```